# Send a payload to the delete request in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I have my add post request working but when I try to pass the same payload to the delete request I get an error. The api is the same value and accepts the same payload. Just a different request POST and DELETE.

The payload looks like this for each

```
{
 jim : 1234
}
```

This is my add() / POST request (working)

```
add() {
      let jim = {
        jim: this.htmlvalue
      };
      return this.myApiService.create({},
        jim).subscribe(response => {
          console.log('response', response);
          this.reset();
        },error => {
          console.log('error', error);
        }
      );
    }
```

And this is what I'm trying to do with my delete request

```
delete(jim) {
      let jim = {
        jim: this.htmlvalue
      };
      return this.myApiService.remove({},
       jim).subscribe(response => {
          console.log('response', response);
          this.reset();
        },error => {
          console.log('error', error);
        });
    }
```

The error message is

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

This relates to the .remove({}, jim) in the delete request

Comment: How does `this.myApiService.remove` look like?

Comment: Your 'remove' method in your myApiService, what does it's signature look like?

Comment: The `httpClient` [delete function](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete) does not accept a body. You may want to use the [request function](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) instead, although without seeing your `myApiService`, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @user184994 I've updated the description to include myApiService